# JavaScript event in class on dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have the below class, but have run into two problems:

1. I can only get it to work on existing elements, but I need to declare it for elements that later will be created dynamically. I believe a check on the eventlistener is needed, and perhaps using MutationObserver... and now I'm so far out of my depth...
2. If I do create two instances of the bar, for two elements that do exist, then when I mousedown or mouseup, they seem to target the same element. I believe this is because I'm using a prototype, and not this. But I can not get it to work if I use this.mousedown=func... instead.

```js
var bar = (function(){
  var me = this;
  function bar(id){
    me._id=id;
  }
  
  bar.prototype.mousedown=function(code){
    el().addEventListener('mousedown', code, false);
    return this;
  }
  
  bar.prototype.mouseup=function(code){
    el().addEventListener('mouseup', code, false);
    return this;
  }
  
  this.el=function(){
    return document.getElementById(me._id);
  };
  this.css=function(){
    return el().style;
  };
  
  return bar;
})();
```

which I then use like this, for an existing element, in my jsfiddle a DIV with id batman.

Don't pay too much attention to the css() function and color changes, those are just for testing. The final code will hopefully have some ajax calls etc inside them instead.

```
function foo(s){
  return new bar(s);
}

foo("batman")
  .mousedown(
    function(e){
      css().background="green";
    }
  )
  .mouseup(
    function(e){
      css().background="orange";
    }
  );
```

[full jsbin code with sample](https://jsbin.com/nafumezapo/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var me = this;`: Here, `this` refers to the `window` variable because you're not inside an object. So when you create another instance of `bar` (the **function** declared line 3), `me._id=id;` overrides the previous id because `this` reference didn't change.

Use a more object-oriented approach.

```js
var bar = function(id){
  this.id=id;
}

bar.prototype.element=function(){
    return document.getElementById(this.id);
}

bar.prototype.css=function(){
    return this.element().style;
}

bar.prototype.mousedown=function(code){
    var that = this;
    this.element().addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
      code(that);
    }, false);
    return this;
}
  
bar.prototype.mouseup=function(code){
  var that = this;
  this.element().addEventListener('mouseup', function(e){
      code(that);
  }, false);
  return this;
}

function foo(s){
  return new bar(s);
}

foo("batman")
  .mousedown(
    function(obj){
      obj.css().background="green";
    }
  )
  .mouseup(
    function(obj){
      obj.css().background="orange";
    }
  );

foo("batman2")
  .mousedown(
    function(obj){
      obj.css().background="green";
    }
  )
  .mouseup(
    function(obj){
      obj.css().background="orange";
    }
  );
```

```css
.mydiv{
  background-color:#e72629;
  padding:5px;
  color:#ffffff;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  
  
  <div class="mydiv" id="batman">
  hello world!
</div>
  
  <div class="mydiv" id="batman2">
  hello world 2!
</div>

  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you so much, exactly what I needed and looks much better. What about a dynamically crated element, one that doesnt exist yet. Adding foo("batman3") now, without any html code spits out errors.

Comment: @Jason This code should work for dynamically created elements because it gets the element by id through `document.getElementById()`.

Comment: check here, I renamed batman2 to batman3 in the JS code. There is no such element in the html, and it spits out errors in the console. [jsbin link](https://jsbin.com/qunewecino/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

Comment: @Jason Then just check if `element()` returns `undefined`.

Comment: thank you. I did that with my previous code and it just didnt work, but it works with the code you gave me so.. perfect. thank you!!!

Comment: But after dynamically creating an element and naming it say "batman3", how to i get the bar() events to work? Do I need to refresh the dom or something to let it know it exists?

Comment: @Jason You need to create the DOM element before you create your object or the `bar.mousedown()` and `bar.mouseup()` functions will not get the element through `element()` and thus will not be able to register the event.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182808/discussion-between-jason-and-systemglitch).